# Altered Django project structure and now I'm getting an ImportError when I run manage.py runserver

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, importerror

So I modified my Django structure to look like this

```
/ project_name
    / apps
        / customAppHere
    / config (was project_name)
        / settings.py
        / urls.py
        / wsgi.py
    / static
    / templates
    - manage.py
```

But when I run ./manage.py runserver I get:

> ImportError: No module named 'project_name'

Using Django 1.6.2 in a virtualenv.  I'm assuming its a path issue but would like clarity on what the issue is and the best way to resolve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When generating `manage.py`, django adds a line to let it know where to import `settings.py`:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project_name.settings")
```

You need to change that to `config.settings` instead, since you've moved it.